# Cómo saber si hay datos que están a la vez en dos tablas MySQL PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy acabando de realizar un programa con unos datos que me han dado y tengo una duda, que no estoy siendo capaz de resolver.

Básicamente tengo dos tablas:

```
diccionario_auxiliar

ean char 13.
grupo_articulos int 11
nombre_grupo varchar 50

articulos_nuevos_definitiva

diccionario_auxiliar

ean char 13.
grupo_articulos int 11
MODELO varchar 50
```

Básicamente, quiero meter grupo_articulos y nombre_grupo en articulos_nuevos_definitiva en función del ean, que es la clave primaria. Hago la siguiente sentencia:

```
UPDATE articulos_nuevos_definitiva art INNER JOIN diccionario_auxiliar d ON d.ean = art.ean
SET art.grupo_articulos = d.grupo_articulos, art.MODELO = d.nombre_grupo
```

pero no afecta a ningún registro. Entonces no sé si es que tengo algún fallo en la sentencia SQL (MySQL no me devuelve ningún error) o si es que realmente no hay datos con el mismo ean en ambas tablas (hay muchísimos datos y es inviable comprobarlo a mano).

Para intentar comprobarlo he realizado sentencias como ésta:

```
SELECT * FROM `diccionario_auxiliar` a, `articulos_nuevos_definitiva` art WHERE a.ean=art.ean
```

pero tampoco me devuelve registro alguno.

Por tanto... ¿estoy fallando con mis sentencias SQL o realmente no hay eans que coinciden en ambas tablas? Lo normal es que al menos hubiera alguno que coincidiera. En caso de que mis sentencias estén mal o de que haya alguna forma mejor de comprobar si hay eans que coincidieran, se agradece feedback. Muchas gracias.

P.D. Este programa lo estoy realizando con PHP, usando SQL en un SGBD MySQL.

Comment: En tu consulta `SELECT * FROM ...` cambia el asterisco por un campo de las tablas, por ejemplo `a.ean`. Esto debería devolverte datos.

Comment: No. He ejecutado esto ```a.ean FROM `diccionario_auxiliar` a, `articulos_nuevos_definitiva` art WHERE a.ean=art.ean``` pero devuelve tb una consulta vacía

Comment: ¿Tienes algún registro en tu BBDD que esté en ambas tablas? Me refiero a que cumpla la condición `a.ean = art.ean`.

Comment: Tengo una duda... ¿Quieres re-insertar los registros repetidos?¿Actualizar los existentes? o ¿Ingresar nuevos registros y que los antiguos queden?

Comment: No, los que ya existen no se insertan y simplemente insertar los que no existen.

Comment: Por que estás haciendo un UPDATE. Update actualiza los registros que ya existen en la tabla. `UPDATE is a DML statement that modifies rows in a table.`

Comment: Lo que tu quieres hacer, es un insert donde ignore los registros existentes en la tabla. A lo cual hay un par de métodos que pueden funcionar

Comment: Te deje una respuesta debajo, espero te ayude ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Los que ya existen no se insertan y simplemente insertar los que no existen.

Hay 3 posibles soluciones a tu requerimiento, y para ello solo debes tener claro cual es la llave primaria:

- `INSERT IGNORE` : Si el registro ya existe en la tabla, será ignorado y no volverá a entrar.
- `REPLACE` : Si el registro existe, se sobre-escribe, pero si no existe, se creará.
- `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`: Al especificar un `ON DUPLICATE KEY` si el registro se repite según la llave, este se actualizará. Si no hay duplicado, se inserta normalmente
  ** Cabe agregar, que puedes agregar condiciones de cambio si quieres que no se actualice un viejo registro, y se cree otro con información actualizada.

---

Ejemplos:

`INSERT IGNORE`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 'miTabla'
SET 'idUnica' = 'valorID'
```

`REPLACE`

```
REPLACE INTO `miTabla`
SET `idUnica` = 'valorID'
```

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO 
   'miTabla'(idUnica) 
VALUES 
   ('valorID') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'idUnica' = 'valorID';
```